# Gradle sync not working after updating to version 3.3.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.3, android-gradle-plugin-3.3.0

After updating to Android Studio Gradle plugin 3.3.0 my sync process is not working anymore.

I have a multi-module and multi-flavor Android application process with a base module and different other "upper" modules that depend on this base.

I get a lot of errors in some of the upper modules regarding not being able to resolve dependencies.

For example here some of the errors I get in the webview module:

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env1DebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env1DebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env1ReleaseFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env1ReleaseFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env1ReleaseFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env2DebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env2DebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env2DebugFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env2ReleaseFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':webview@env2ReleaseFeature/compileClasspath': Could not resolve androidx.core:core:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: webview
```

Looks like there is an issue of conflicting dependency versions but I didn't have it before with 3.2.1

I don't want to solve it by manually excluding a version of the dependency that creates a conflict from all other dependencies because that's a lot of unnecessary work in my opinion.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to 3.3.2. I don't know why it works but it did in my case with the same exact problem.